# Skipping over an array value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to Javascript. I've been using it to automate things in Google Sheets.

I've created an array that has several variables inside of them to import from other places, which works fine.

```
  var rangeToWrite = summarySheet.getRange(i, 6, 1, 11);
rangeToWrite.setValues([[raceInfo, level, achievements, audit, professionName1, rankCurrent1, professionName2, rankCurrent2, robot, Drov, Tarl, Rukh]]);
```

I just can't for the life of me figure out how to leave a blank space, or 'skip' over a variable without changing it on the Spreadsheet. I've tried using ,, and "" in place of one of the variables, but it ends up overwriting all the information with either undefined for ,, or just erasing everything in the cell when using "".

TL;DR I want to manually enter information into a cell that is in the middle of the array without it overwriting information in Javascript.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could try to set the holes to `undefined` or `null`. Else, I suppose instead of writing the whole range at once, you have to write the values one by one, or split the range into sub-ranges separated by the holes, and write these sub-ranges.

Comment: Add a tag for Google sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried using ... "" in place of one of the variables, ...

Maybe you got the quotes mis-paired? This works to leave a blank instead of `level`.

```
rangeToWrite.setValues([[raceInfo, '', achievements, ...
                                   ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in a empty object

```
{}
```

Comment: No luck. :( It just fills in the cell with {} haha. :(

Thanks though!